# Parent too large after child white-space: nowrap

Tags: css

In this image, there is extra space in the last box as indicated by the red arrows. How can this be fixed?

The last phrase has `white-space: nowrap` around it.

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/glittle/qyemuato/)

```css
.outer {
  text-align: center;
}
.outer div {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: #d89648 4px solid;
  color: #D97A23;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding: 10px 30px 12px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.test {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bad div {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This containing box resizes according to the amount of text in it, up to a maximum width. The round borders stay nice when the box is taller because the radius used is much bigger.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This has few words and the box is smaller.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This box has just as much text in it as the next one, but the next one should be narrower.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer bad">
  <div>
    This part of this sentence can wrap, but <span class="test">not this part, which must stay together.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jacob-Gray, I wondered how to do embed the fiddle!

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here. Just remove the `white-space: nowrap` from the span with class `.test`

Comment: @lonut `<span class="test">not this part, which must stay together.</span>`

Comment: @Huangism, ooh. Ok. I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: This example is contrived... in the real site, the text is variable in size by person and language.

Comment: the container will reach the max-width and then text inside will wrap. but width won't decrease again to shrink on wrapped text. ... In other words, wrapping happens once max-width is reached :) . you can rethink your methode and use the .test class to set the width of the container https://jsfiddle.net/qyemuato/3/ (max-width on parent then display:table + width:0 or any min-value you wish, cause table(html or cstyled element shrink/expands according to content)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display:block;` to `.test`:

```css
.outer {
  text-align: center;
}
.outer div {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: #d89648 4px solid;
  color: #D97A23;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding: 10px 30px 12px 30px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.test {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:block;
}
.bad div {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This containing box resizes according to the amount of text in it, up to a maximum width. The round borders stay nice when the box is taller because the radius used is much bigger.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This has few words and the box is smaller.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div>
    This box has just as much text in it as the next one, but the next one should be narrower.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer bad">
  <div>
    This part of this sentence can wrap, but <span class="test">not this part, which must stay together.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would involve changing the CSS for this case. When it doesn't need to wrap, I need it to not wrap. I've updated the fiddle and used `test` in the second box too, where it does not wrap. See https://jsfiddle.net/glittle/qyemuato/2/